# What is the purpose of raise Exception.Create at @Somefunction?

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-10-seattle

The [official documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Exceptions) says that:

> In general, the form of a raise statement is:
>
> ```
> raise object at address
> ```
>
> where object and at address are both optional...

And later:

> Use this option to raise the exception from an earlier point in the stack

I find this confusing, normally I thought that a stack trace of an exception points me reliably to the function where the exception was created (assuming that the required stack frames are avaliable and nothing was inlined).

What's the use case here? Why should I manipulate the stack trace of my exception?

Comment: @Ken White Thank you for helping me out. I did actually search for an answer but didn't find the referenced question. Perhaps because the word `at` is part of the most exception stack traces...

Comment: No problem. :-) I remembered writing an answer to the linked question, so I knew it existed. A quick search turned it up for me (I searched on *raise at address*, and it was among the first four or five results).